# In R and read_delim, how do I read a CSV without quotes or trailing characters?

Tags: r, csv, separator, readr, trailing

On a machine with Ubuntu and R 3.6.2 I want to open a CSV file

In LibreOffice I saw that the file has a ";" separator and ISO-8859-1 encoding

It is a file with no column names (header) and the data is in Brazilian Portuguese. Dates in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS format

There are some columns with unique identification codes, so with the exception of dates, I would like to keep all columns as a string

Here the content of the first line of the CSV as an example:

345365;99901000001201633;;BB – Banco do Brasil S.A.;Respondido;01/01/2016 09:24:13;consultar meu cpf . no spc e serasa;Consulta do cpf no serasa e spc;25/01/2016 23:59:59;NÃO;NÃO;Pelo sistema (com avisos por email);Internet;604629;Economia e Finanças;Economia;1;25/01/2016 11:30:39;Prezado(a) Sr(a). ,  Encaminhamos, em anexo, resposta ao seu pedido de informação.  Atenciosamente,  Serviço de Informação ao Cidadão do Banco do Brasil – SICBB  Recurso  Conforme a Lei 12527/11 em seu artigo Art. 15, no caso de indeferimento de acesso a informações ou às razões da negativa do acesso, poderá o interessado interpor recurso contra a decisão no prazo de 10 (dez) dias a contar da sua ciência.  Parágrafo único. O recurso será dirigido à autoridade hierarquicamente superior à que exarou a decisão impugnada, que deverá se manifestar no prazo de 5 (cinco) dias.;Acesso Concedido;Resposta solicitada inserida no e-SIC

So I tried it like this first:

```
library(readr)
asks_2016 <- read_delim("2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv", 
                                         ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                                         locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
```

But the dataframe returned is all NA

I had these warning messages:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  .default = col_logical(),
  X1 = col_double()
)
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
|==================================================================================| 100%  291 MB
Warning: 1923814 parsing failures.
row col               expected actual                                 file
  1  X1 no trailing characters        '2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv'
  1  X2 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE            '2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv'
  1  X3 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE            '2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv'
  1  X4 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE            '2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv'
  1  X5 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE            '2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv'
... ... ...................... ...... ....................................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

Please, does anyone know the correct way to load this CSV?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a default column format using `col_types` and `cols()`. Below, we specify everything should be read in as a character.

```
library(readr)
asks_2016 <- read_delim("2016/20200201_Pedidos_csv_2016.csv", 
                        ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                        locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
                        col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
```

Then turn the date column into POSIXct.

```
asks_2016$datetime <- as.POSIXct(asks_2016$X18, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

head(asks_2016)

# A tibble: 1 x 22
  X1     X2     X3    X4       X5     X6      X7       X8     X9     X10   X11   X12     X13   X14   X15    X16   X17   X18    X19               X20   X21     datetime           
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>             <chr> <chr>   <dttm>             
1 345365 99901~ NA    "BB â\u~ Respo~ 01/01/~ consult~ Consu~ 25/01~ "NÃ\~ "NÃ\~ Pelo s~ Inte~ 6046~ Econo~ Econ~ 1     25/01~ "Prezado(a) Sr(a~ Aces~ Respos~ 2016-01-25 11:30:39
```

Comment: Thank you very much @EugeneChong , but I think this file still has something that is going unnoticed. Because he continues with NA on all lines, even with his suggestions. I still do not understand

Comment: I put the file here if you want to look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C8deV1uWfIvXB1eGOujzffmF2M34653B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @ReinaldoChaves, I checked out the file, and I do get the same error when using the whole dataset as opposed to your sample data. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to fix it, but my assumption is that one or more lines of the data has a different structure than the first line. I would try to find one of those broken lines and then edit your question to include that new, broken line in the sample data.